# Powershell to upload text string to blob through Azure Automation account

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation

There is no local machine to store a intermittent file. Read data from Blob to string variable, after modification of text string, need to upload the content to destination azure blob through azure automation account using powershell. Everything need to be done in Azure automation account.

Answer (score 0):

> Read data from Blob to string variable

**If it is the big blob, then Output the blob content to a stream else Output the blob content as string.**

```
$StorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName
$Blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Container $container -Blob $Filename
$Text = $blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
Write-Output $Text
```

To get the contents of the blob as a string and pipe it to convertfrom-json directly:

```
$blobs | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -AsString | ConvertFrom-Json ...
```

There are different download options available for Text, Byte, File and Stream in (`$Blob.ICloudBlob | Get-Member | where {$_.Name -like "Download*"} | select Name`) gives you:

> DownloadBlockList
> DownloadBlockListAsync
> DownloadRangeToByteArray
> DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync
> DownloadRangeToStream
> DownloadRangeToStreamAsync
> DownloadText
> DownloadTextAsync
> DownloadToByteArray
> DownloadToByteArrayAsync
> DownloadToFile
> DownloadToFileAsync
> DownloadToStream
> DownloadToStreamAsync

After modification of blob content, for uploading the modified content to the destination blob with the help of Azure Automation and PowerShell commands, please refer the below references will helps you for the following above:

- [Provision Azure Storage account, automatic file upload using PowerShell](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/01/26/provision-azure-storage-account-and-automate-file-upload-and-deletion-using-powershell/)
- [Upload Files to Azure Blob Storage using Power Automate Desktop](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage-using-power-automate-desktop/ba-p/2316960)